# Can I use Cyberark credential provider to pull DB credentials on NPoco autogenerated file?

Tags: c#, .net, npoco

I have an old project where the database class was automatically generated by the NPoco T4 Template. Now I want to use the Cyberark credentials provider to store and provide the database credentials. I would like to retain the NPoco file and get the credentials as needed using Cyberark.

Are there any drawbacks to this implementation and would editing the generated autogenerated file break the application? If you have solved this problem before kindly provide pointers.

Comment: What keeps you away from implementation? Then you know if you face any real specific problems that you can ask and we try to answer. You should use git to be able to rollback in case you break anything

Comment: @SirRufo I wanted to understand the possible full extent of editing an autogenerated file. Especially by editing the main logic flow the database methods are meant to follow. I learned a few things like some significant edits can lead to the class file being wiped clean, and also for some changes, I would need to update certain libraries to be able to make those changes.